# Correlation between 3 independent samples

Tags: r, correlation, sample

I performed an experiment where participants from 3 countries filles a questionaire. I wish to know if the result from 1 country can be predictive of the results from another country. I dont think that regression is a good choice here as each observation is from 1 country only so I cant fill an independent and dependent variables that will both have values in the data set.
I though maybe on correlation ? any other ideas?
the dataset looks like this:

```
 | France |US  |Israel|
 | -0.3   |NA  |NA    |
 |NA      |-0.5|NA    |
 |NA      |NA  |0.7   |
```

I would appreciate any help to code this in r

Comment: Provide a sample of your data using `dput(head(YourData, 15))` and paste it into your question as a code block. The data you posted looks like a correlation matrix with missing values? Or is this data from one question asked in France, a different question asked in US, and a third question asked in Israel. Just as regression, correlation requires the same measurements be taken in all three countries.

Comment: Thank you
It is not a correlation matrix. Is is a data frame with 3 columns. Each row is a person measurement. As each person is from 1 country only, each row has only 1 value. All the NAs are not missing. They are simply empty cell.
I need a way to measure the bivariate correlation between the values of each country.

Comment: Based on the data you have provided it is not possible. You have not provided a sample of your data so all we have to work with is the three lines you provided. Each country has only a single value and no two countries have a value on the same row.